# How do I Change Website JavaScript Code if It's in a Function

Tags: javascript, html

With most websites their javascript code can be manipulated in some way with the console. However, my friend when making his website decided to put this bundled javascript into a function. We are wondering if it is still possible to change it.

Comment: There's no way to know without seeing the code. But javascript gets loaded in the browser. There's nothing inherently insecure about a function, it just depends on how it's coded.

Comment: @Difster the code available for inspection on the website.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears your friend placed their code in an [IIFE](http://benalman.com/news/2010/11/immediately-invoked-function-expression/) otherwise known as an Immediately-Invoked Function Expression. This is used to prevent polluting the global name space. Since JS console only has access to the global space and all of your code is enclosed in an IIFE you can't access any of the JS from the console.